# How can I outsource this duplicate code smell in an extra function? iOS Swift Functions

Tags: ios, swift, dry

I try to refactor this duplicate working code relating to the DRY-Principle. (Swift Version 4) You can download the working code Project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16yjJHYv-G-61wnNcW8rDbnfyYf4SjrJb/view?usp=sharing) (it isn't big).  The problem is that I don't know how I can correctly do this specially for these function's because they use `ViewController` Classes and I couldn't manage it to pass them and to instantiate them than in the outsourced function. I would need to see a concrete implementation of the improved code according to dry because i failed at the implementation part, i just know that the dry principle would be clean but i dont know how to do it in real code

**WHAT I HAVE:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public final class MainCoordinator {

    var navigationController: UINavigationController

    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
        self.navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }

func showHome() {
    var vc: HomeViewController
    var i = 0
    for viewController in navigationController.viewControllers {
        if (viewController.isKind(of: HomeViewController.self)) {
            vc = viewController as! HomeViewController
            navigationController.viewControllers.remove(at: i)
            navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            return
        }
        i+=1
    }

    vc = HomeViewController.instantiate()
    vc.coordinator = self
    navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

func showDetail() {
    var vc: DetailViewController
    var i = 0
    for viewController in navigationController.viewControllers {
        if (viewController.isKind(of: DetailViewController.self)) {
            vc = viewController as! DetailViewController
            navigationController.viewControllers.remove(at: i)
            navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            return
        }
        i+=1
    }

    vc = DetailViewController.instantiate()
    vc.coordinator = self
    navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

func showMasterDetail() {
    var vc: MasterDetailViewController
    var i = 0
    for viewController in navigationController.viewControllers {
        if (viewController.isKind(of: MasterDetailViewController.self)) {
            vc = viewController as! MasterDetailViewController
            navigationController.viewControllers.remove(at: i)
            navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            return
        }
        i+=1
    }

    vc = MasterDetailViewController.instantiate()
    vc.coordinator = self
    navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

}
```

**SOMETHING LIKE THAT I WOULD WANT:**

This is a sample/pseudo code because it's not working. You should get an idea of what I mean. How would the real code look like?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public final class MainCoordinator {

//..

func showHome() {
    present(HomeViewController)
}

func showDetail() {
    present(DetailViewController)
}

func showMasterDetail() {
    present(MasterDetailViewController)
}

func present(myClass: Class){

    var vc: myClass
    var i = 0
    for viewController in navigationController.viewControllers {
        if (viewController.isKind(of: myClass.self)) {
            vc = viewController as! myClass
            navigationController.viewControllers.remove(at: i)
            navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            return
        }
        i+=1
    }

    vc = myClass.instantiate()
    vc.coordinator = self
    navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do and what your problem is. Is there a compiler error somewhere? What exactly do you want us to solve?

Comment: oh i am sorry i will try to explain it clearer. I want to achive a cleaner code because as you can see the functions showHome(), showDetail() and showMasterDetail() are very similar to each other. And according to the DONT-REPEAT-YORSELF scheme this isn't clean because of the dupliticity, how can i outsource the duplicate code into a new function. This new function should be than called in every show/detail/masterdetail do know what i mean ? How would the improved code look like according to dry

Comment: Ok. But what is wrong with the direction you are taking in the second code block? That looks like a good improvement to me.

Comment: Yesterday i tried to make such a outsourced function but i didn't manage it to pass the uiviewcontroller class as a parameter, the code in the second part is just pseudo code that doesn't work

Comment: yes I just know the direction of the improvement, but I fail at the implementation

Comment: I've added a possible solution that uses a protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would introduce a `Coordinatable` protocol:

```
protocol Coordinatable: class {
  var coordinator: MainCoordinator? { get set }
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, Coordinatable {
  var coordinator: MainCoordinator?
}

class MainCoordinator {
  func showHome() {
    let viewController = HomeViewController() // Or instantiate any other way
    present(viewController)
  }

  func present<T: UIViewController>(_ viewController: T) where T: Coordinatable {
    // Do whatever you want here
    viewController.coordinator = self
    navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: first of all thank you very much for your answer yes thats what i wanted to know, i will try to implement it in my project the way you explained it, now i am in the train, i can test the solution in the evening today, you will hear from me if everything works as expected :) but thanks for now!

Comment: I have tested your solution in my project, its perfectly working for me thank you so much !